# How to make slanted top border with two inline divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site with several sections on one page. I wanne make a top border for each section that has slanted transparent arrow in the middle. I did try to use 2 divs and display them inline and add a left and right border. To illustrate what i wanne accomplish plz see: [Website](https://www.wallmob.com/company/about/)

My problem is that the border looks all messed up and when i resize the screen the borders change position. I'm using wordpress and bootstrap to create the page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure you update your question with relevant code. See this FAQ for details. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: If you want help you need to show your CSS + HTML. No one can debug a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your code looks like  and how you want it, but here's a sample that can get you started and you can modify the code to match your needs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent-div-border">
    <div class="down-arrow">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.parent-div-border {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        border-left:0px solid transparent;
        border-right:0px solid transparent;
        border-top:50px solid #1d1d1d;
}
.down-arrow {
        margin 0 auto;
        border-left:50px solid transparent;
        border-right:50px solid transparent;
        border-top:50px solid #1d1d1d;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left:45%;
        float: left;
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yGSYn/1/

Comment: Perfect! Thx for the help  - just what i wanted. And for the future i will include some code :)

Comment: You can always mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this... One div though.

HTML

```
<div class="cutout-border">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cutout-border {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5em;
  background-color: black;
}

.cutout-border:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto 2em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5em solid white;
  border-left: 5em solid transparent; 
  border-right: 5em solid transparent; 
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/brbcoding/full/FcDtJ)**

Comment: the demo link is broken

Comment: shouldn't be... I think I fixed it right before you posted

Comment: Right, it is working now :-)